# Rails Asset Pipeline - wrong fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails 4 application has `new.html.erb` which has a reference to `form.html.erb`:

```html
# app/assets/templates/jobs/new.html.erb
...
<ng-include src="'<%= asset_path("jobs/form.html") %>'"></ng-include>
...

# app/assets/templates/jobs/form.html.erb
my form is here
```

([`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) is [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) directive)

The problem is, that when `form.html.erb` changes, the production environment still loads the old `form.html.erb`. This is happening probably because `new.html.erb` hasn't been changed, and therefore has the same old fingerprint, which points to `form.html.erb` with the old fingerprint.

What is the Rails way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, assets are "precompiled" only in production/deployed environments. That means that by default there shouldn't be a folder at `public/assets/` while you develop (Sprockets compiles assets on-the-fly for you in development mode).

If you accidentally have run `rails assets:precompile` in development, you'll have an extra folder here (`public/assets/`) which does not get checked in to your repository.

But if it does exist, then its existence overrides Sprocket's development mode setting to recompile on every pageload, forcing your browser to load the already compiled (and ***stale***) asset from `public/assets/`... If you do have a folder at `public/assets/`, be sure to remove it completely with `rm -rf public/assets/`

(Ironically, running `rails assets:precompile` or `rake assets:precompile`, while it does force a one-time recompile and seemingly gives you your latest JS compile, doing this in development is typically what *causes* the problem of Sprockets getting stuck in the first place)

Next, force Sprockets to bust the thumbprint cache using:

```
rails assets:clean
rails assets:clobber    
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

You must actually touch this empty `tmp/restart.txt` file -- not merely restart your Rails dev environment, to force Sprockets to bust the thumbprint cache.

To debug further, set `assets.debug = true` in your environment file.