# Rails + AWS CloudFront + CORS for AngularJS HTML templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I am deploying a Rails 4 application using AngularJS as our front-end MVC framework, and I'd like to deploy our assets through a CDN. After [running into issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23372225/2434476) with getting the properly fingerprinted URLs when calling `asset_path` within my AngularJS routing javascript file, I decided to eliminate the [AssetSync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem. To replace AssetSync, I would like to simply use Amazon CloudFront on top of my Rails server serving its own static assets. This works great for my CSS and JS files, but unfortunately I run into CORS issues when trying to serve my HTML templates for Angular as assets:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools console output]

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE 4/30:**

I was finally able to get my Rails server to set the proper 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on assets with the [rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) by following the instructions in [this Github issue](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/32). Now when I run `curl` to fetch the files from CloudFront, I see the proper headers. However, when I run `curl` to send an `OPTIONS` request, I'm still getting a 403 Forbidden. Check out the two screenshots below:

The GET request for the asset looks good:

[image: Curl GET Request]

But the OPTIONS request doesn't....

[image: Curl GET Request]

Comment: you need to do this on your S3 bucket CORS policy.

Comment: @j_mcnally I'm not using S3, but instead delivering the assets from my Rails server (hosted at Heroku)

Comment: Your rails app needs to send what ever headers it wants cached to cloud front if you are using your rails server as your cloudfront origin then...

Comment: @j_mcnally unfortunately getting the proper headers from the Rails app doesn't work. Check out the update I added onto the question from yesterday - the headers are there for my `GET` from CloudFront, but the `OPTIONS` request (which Chrome/Firefox perform before the GET) returns a 403 Forbidden. All of the links that I've found so far seem to suggest that CloudFront won't be able to do what I want it to, but holding out hope that someone has solved this issue.

Comment: Does your rails app respond to an options request?

Comment: Yes, the rails app responds properly to the options request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been asked for this solution a couple times, so I thought I would post what worked for us here.

It seems that Rails will set the CORS headers correctly for CSS and JS files only. However, you can use the [rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to set custom headers for resources. We added the following configuration to our `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '/assets/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :options]
    end
end
```

We were able to set the CORS headers on only our assets because our asset prefix was set to `/assets` with the following (default) line in our `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
```

To complete the AWS CloudFront configuration, follow @Cfstat's advice in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23691414/2434476) and make sure that you've edited the default cache behavior on AWS CloudFront to enable extended verb support. Set `Allowed HTTP Methods` to include `GET` and `OPTIONS`.

The last bit of configuration to get all of this working is to set your asset host to point to AWS CloudFront. We wanted to use an environment variable, so we used the following line in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['ASSET_HOST']}"
```

Then we just set the `ASSET_HOST` env variable to point to our CloudFront URL.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to enable the use of OPTIONS on your cloudfront cache behavior.

You can do this in the console by selecting your distribution, and going to the behaviors tab.

Edit the default cache behavior and enable extended verb support:

```
Allowed HTTP Methods
GET, HEAD, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
```