# EOFError when loading webpack javascript in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a file `app/javascript/packs/application.js` in my Rails 6 project. When I load the local dev version of the site, it attempts to retrieve that via http://localhost:4000/packs/js/application-ed3ae63cdf581cdb86b0.js (I'm running on a custom port to avoid conflicts with another app), but the request for the JS file fails with a 500:

```
Puma caught this error: end of file reached (EOFError)
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/net_http_hacked.rb:53:in `begin_request_hacked'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/http_streaming_response.rb:60:in `response'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/http_streaming_response.rb:29:in `headers'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:120:in `perform_request'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.3.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:21:in `perform_request'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
/Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

This file doesn't exist locally:

```sh
$ ls public/packs/js/application-ed3ae63cdf581cdb86b0.js
ls: public/packs/js/application-ed3ae63cdf581cdb86b0.js: No such file or directory
```

but a version with another fingerprint does (and is non-empty):

```sh
$ ls -alh public/packs/js/application-*
-rw-r--r--  1 sam  staff   188K 24 Feb 17:58 public/packs/js/application-fdef50bf044896f1dc71.js
-rw-r--r--  1 sam  staff   212K 24 Feb 17:58 public/packs/js/application-fdef50bf044896f1dc71.js.map
```

I can't get my site to request the right files. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24443099/328817), I've tried

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

but to no avail. I've also tried a private browser window, clearing browser cache and a different browser.

I'm using `bin/server` rather than `bin/webpacker-dev-server` and haven't changed my `webpacker.yml` (it was auto-created on init and then auto-updated when I installed React), but in case it helps, it looks like this:

```yaml
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using webpack-dev-server? Please update with webpacker.yml

Comment: Thanks @razvans. I'm using plain old bin/server. I've added my webpacker.yml to the question.

Comment: Try with the devserver see what happens. I have a similar config running with dev server and no issues. When using the dev server public/packs should contain just manifest.json

Comment: Tru commenting out the dev server config from development. If you are not using it then it shouldn't be there. If you run assets:precompile in dev... Make sure public/packs is empty before precompile. One thing i noticed is if tjr the packs are not there and you enter a page it automatically precompiles

Comment: When using the devserver, pages don't load, I just get `Cannot GET /`. I don't know what's up here. It's worth noting that I've seen the pack javascript load in the past with just `bin/server`.

Comment: Commenting out the dev server config in `webpacker.yml` didn't make a difference (running either type of server). Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Manually clearing out the public/packs folder and re-running `bin/server` did it. Thank you! If you post it as an answer, I'll upvote you.

Comment: I've just discovered the command `bin/webpack`. If I hit this problem again, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Update: I did have the problem again, and `bin/webpack` (plus server restart) didn't help.

Comment: I suggest looking into webpack dev server then. Public/packs is not cleared. If you do "rm public/packs && bin/webpack" does it work?

Comment: That seemed to do it, thanks! I had restarted my computer in the meantime too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that come to mind by seeing that you are not using the dev server, it's very likely to have an old version of your assets in `public/packs`.

Try removing that packs folder and run `bin/server`

Comment: That did it, thank you! I had still got your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528437/eoferror-when-loading-webpack-javascript-in-rails#comment117619607_66528437) of commenting out dev server config in place at the time without realising, but I don't think this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a variant of this problem on another occasion (same error, but files of the right name *were* in `public/packs/js`) and managed to resolve it by no longer running my Rails app on a custom port.

Furthermore, when I then stopped that server and re-ran it with the custom port re-applied, the assets then loaded correctly in that context too.